# Hadoop key is not listing when I tried to access using url

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hdfs

I tried to enable the feature "HDFS encryption".As part of encryption I have created a key.
When I tried below command it is listing the key which I have created.(testkey)

venkat@hdp-poc2:~$ hadoop key list

Listing keys for KeyProvider: KMSClientProvider[http://hdp-poc2.tbu.com:16000/kms/v1/]

testkey

I want to access the same key using url.I have copied same url(http://hdp-poc2.tbu.com:16000/kms/v1/) in the address bar.But it is giving the error.

Network Error (tcp_error)

Please help me how to access the key using URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the rest api calls here
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-kms/index.html

Seems like you have an incorrect URL.